# At least one number with existing regex

Tags: regex

My conditions ...

1. Alpha-Numeric value
2. Only one space or hyphen is allowed
3. Must contain at least one number
4. Cannot start or end with space or hyphen
5. Minimum 2 characters, maximum 16 characters excluding space/hyphen

As of now I prepared the regex

```
^(?=.{2,16}$)([a-zA-Z\d]+)([\s^\-]|[\-^\s]|[a-zA-Z\d]*)([a-z[A-Z\d]+)
```

Its only missing 3rd point.

Test strings
Valid

```
"test one"
"test 2two"
"test3 three222"
"3test-4four"
```

Invalid

```
"-test"
"test-d f"
```

Comment: Must contain at least one number, do you mean spelt out numbers like `one`, too?

Comment: Must contain at least one number means it must have at least one (\d) digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with 2 lookahead conditions:

```
^(?=(?:[a-zA-Z\d][ -]?){2,16}$)(?=[^\d\n]*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z\d]+)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Yv0dP/3)

PS: Note that `test one` is an invalid string as it doesn't have any digit.

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=(?:[a-zA-Z\d][ -]?){2,16}$)`: Positive Lookahead to make sure we have 2 to 16 length of alphanumeric characters
- `(?=\D*\d)`: Positive Lookahead to make sure we have at least one digit
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z\d]+)?`: Match any test that starts with alphanumeric, optionally followed by a single space or hyphen and ends with alphanumeric
- `$`: End

Comment: All good but yet missing the string length excluding hypen or space.

Comment: `(?=.{2,16}$)` will ensure length 2 to 16 and other condition is also fulfilled

Comment: For example ''ex-itshouldpass16" It should pass but its failing here.

Anyway thanks.

Comment: `ex-itshouldpass16` has total 17 characters. Do you want to count alphanumerics only?

Comment: If that's the case then use: `^(?=(?:[a-zA-Z\d][ -]?){2,16}$)(?=[^\d\n]*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z\d]+)?$`